# Masonry images are overlapping

Tags: jquery, reload, masonry

[Check this site and click on view button at the middle of the screen](http://www.ytank.com/tourapp/swipe/demosnew/ss00.html)

When you click on view button images overlapping on each other.

then if you re-size browser it will set automatically as we want.

We have tried to reload using below on view button click

```
$('#menu').click(function() {
    $('.primary-content').masonry('reload'); /* not working */
    $("#cont").show();
    alert ( "abc" );
    $('#test').animate({
        height: 'toggle'        
    }, 500, function() {});
});
```

Comment: Open your console, you have a js error that might be halting the init.

Comment: @patsy which init method you are talking about ? Please give me more details about it.

Comment: "$jumptodiv" is not defined.

Comment: @ Pete TNT, well we resolve that error but the bug is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working link (issue solved link) http://www.ytank.com/tourapp/swipe/demosnew/ss02.html

ref link https://github.com/desandro/masonry/issues/211

need to initialize Masonry before you use Masonry methods.

```
$('.hero-masonry')
  // initialize Masonry
  .masonry()
```